# Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

We have  transaction replication between two server (production and staging) which is running on SQL Server 2008 R2. The distributor is running on the staging server. Now my management is asking to create a copy of database on the production environment and replication few tables to that database. Is it possible to replicate twice? Could you please help me on this. If not possible through replication, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You sure can. Create another publication, add the subset of tables to that, and subscribe the other database to the new publication. NB, this will create another copy of changes for this table at the distributor so take that into account.

Comment: HI Ben, Thanks for your reply. I have quick question, the distributor is running on the staging server. I am creating the database on the same server only. How to create distributor on the publisher now..

Comment: Any server will only ever have one distributor configured for it. So you needn't do any distributor configuration again as you're already publishing from that server. All you need to do now is create the publication, add the articles, and add the subscriber.

Comment: Ben, yes it is working. The distributer is still running in the staging. But i am able to create new publisher and subscriber on the same server. Thank you so much for your help.